# How do I get a jQuery's $.getJson to work on a JSONP result?

Tags: jquery, jsonp, getjson

I have the following Javascript code:

```
$.getJSON('data.jsonp?callback=abcde', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(errorThrown);
})
```

But it causes a `parseError`. Here's the incoming text:

```
abcde({"data":"value"});
```

And here's the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
```

I'm probably missing something really obvious but I've done my research and couldn't find it. Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: What you have should work. Are you sure the response is in JSONP format?

Comment: I think jQuery looks specifically for `callback=?` to determine that it's JSONP, so `callback=abcde` doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `callback=?` instead of `callback=abcde`. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

jQuery looks for this specific string, and then substitutes its internally-generated function name.

```
$.getJSON('data.jsonp?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(errorThrown);
})
```

If you need to use your own callback function, I think you have to use `$.ajax()` rather than the `$.getJSON()` shortcut.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.jsonp",
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: "abcde"
})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
})
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: I tried doing that. The error changes to `jQuery321036538996970944315_1495225433720 was not called`. I suppose this means I have to use the full Ajax call, then?

Comment: That sounds like the server isn't using the `callback=` parameter to produce the output. When jQuery sends `?callback= jQuery321036538996970944315_1495225433720`, the server is supposed to send back `jQuery321036538996970944315_1495225433720({"data": "value"});`

Comment: If the function name is hard-coded into the server, you'll need to use `$.ajax`.

Comment: Right, the function name is, indeed, hard-coded. I'll switch to $.ajax, then. Thanks!